# Transistor Switch Output Current Increasing

Tags: transistors, switches, bjt

I'm using a BJT switch to send a 48 V, 2.5 mA signal (thanks for all the help in the past!). I've been tuning the resistance value I need to output 2.5 mA and noticed that the output current is considerably higher than what my simulation is telling me it should be.

Specifically, with 200 Ω at the emitter of the PNP, my simulation is telling me I should see ~1.57 mA at the output. However, I'm measuring almost 2 mA. Even weirder is that when I first give the 5 V switching signal, the current starts at about 1.7 mA and rises until is "saturates" at about 2 mA.

I know there's some amount of variation when dealing with real and particular components, but I'm curious why the current is so high, and why the output current changes with time...

I'm using a 2N5551 NPN and a 2N5401 PNP transistor.

I'd appreciate any insights!

Here's the schematic of my circuit:
[image]

And here are the test results:
[image]

Comment: are the transistors warming up?  Beta changes with temperature.

Comment: They weren't warm to the touch... that's not to say their temperature didn't change at all though.

Comment: ~75-96mW in Q1, it should slightly warm up.  What does the datasheet say about beta/°C?

Comment: @asultan Just wandered by. Is this supposed to be a constant current 2.5 mA driver with a 48 V compliance?

Comment: Not seeing anything in the datasheet about beta vs. °C... I've seen it on other BJT datasheets but I checked a few for the 2N5401 and there's nothing.

Comment: @jonk yeah, constant current 2.5 mA... I know the load needs 48 V, if that's what you mean by compliance?

Comment: @asultan It's a switch if it needs 48 V and will draw *some* current that may be up to 2.5 mA or so. It's a current source if it *needs* 2.5 mA and may require up to 48 V but where it could be less than that. It is one. Or it is the other. But your writing suggests to me that you are looking for a consistent current, not a consistent voltage. Can you clarify more? Please?

Comment: It's a switch: it needs 48 V and will draw up to 2.5 mA. Sorry for the confusion!